# Sort posts with custom post type on custom taxonomy page

Tags: wordpress

Ok, here is the deal. I have a custom post type `paints`, also I registered a custom taxonomy `lkm` for these products. I have a `taxonomy-lkm.php` template, where I can get all posts from a specific custom category(taxonomy). For example, on page `/lkm/polyurethane/` I can get all posts from this custom category.

But I want to sort these posts `ASC`, not `DESC`. How can I do this, if I'm using `while(have_posts)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Since I'm using the custom taxonomy `lkm` with custom post type `paints`, I've created a custom page for that `taxonomy-lkm.php`.

On this page I can catch a query of custom posts `paints` with specific taxonomy, like: on page `/acrilyc` I'll get all paints in category `acrilyc`. But the issue was that this array sorted by date in DESC order, but I need ASC.

So, there is solution:

Template `taxonomy-lkm.php`

```
<?php
get_header();

$termId = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var('taxonomy' ) )->term_id; //get the ID of current taxonomy
$query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'paints', // name of post type.
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'ASC',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'lkm',   // taxonomy name
        'field' => 'term_id', 
        'terms' => $termId,    // term id, term slug or term name
    )
)
) );
if ( $query -> have_posts() ) :

while ( $query -> have_posts() ) :
        $query -> the_post(); ?>
    .................HTML TEMPLATE
<?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
    endif;
?>
```

Now all posts are sorted as ASC.